# Run bash script without chmod

Tags: bash, macos, unix, chmod

I'm creating bash scripts with `.sh` extensions, performing smiple tasks, but every new script I have to modify with `chmod` to run. I see that repositories I download from github/bitbucket containing scripts don't need this and can be run out of the box. How can I achieve this, so when someone download my repository can run this without running `chmod +x` first. I'm working on MacOS Big Sur

Comment: You can execute it with `bash script.sh`

Comment: Change your umask so that newly created files are executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I you `chmod +x` the file locally, git will see that as a change to the file, and you can push that change so that anybody else who clones the repo has the executable permissions:

```
chmod +x script.sh
git add script.sh
git commit -m'make script.sh executable'
git push # if you are on a tracking branch
```

then is will be executable for everybody

I think that is how the repositories that you downloaded accomplished that.

Answer (score 0):

usually in unix, simply `bash [scrip_name].sh` is enough

In MacOS also, same might be enough